# assign value from one dataframe to another by rank using loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have two dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Qty': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'], 'Count': [2,1,5,5,6,1,1]})

print(df1)
  Qty  Count
0   1      2
1   2      1
2   3      5
3   4      5
4   5      6
5   6      1
6   7      1

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'id': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], 'Score': [10,9,8,7,6,5,4]})

print(df2)
  id  Score
0  A     10
1  B      9
2  C      8
3  D      7
4  E      6
5  F      5
6  G      4
```

what I need is to assign the highest qty of df1 to the df2 using the id that has the best score, but the id can only be assigned 3 times.

this is what I expect

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'id': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], 'Score': [10,9,8,7,6,5,4], 'Assigns': [[7,6,5],[5,5,5],[5,5,4],[4,4,4],[4,3,3],[3,3,3], [2,2,1] ]})

print(df3)
  id  Score    Assigns
0  A     10  [7, 6, 5]
1  B      9  [5, 5, 5]
2  C      8  [5, 5, 4]
3  D      7  [4, 4, 4]
4  E      6  [4, 3, 3]
5  F      5  [3, 3, 3]
6  G      4  [2, 1, 1]
```

Does anyone know how to do it ? Thanks

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how you get [7,6,5] then [5,5,5]?

Comment: yeah sure @ScottBoston , I need to assign the count from the df1 to the df2 by the best score. For example, Qty 7 is the greatest in df1 and i want to assign it to the best id by score in df2, so the 7 goes to the id A, then the second greatest in df1 is 6's and it has only one, so you assign it to the id A, and then you have 6 5's  and you assign one to the id A bc u can only assign 3.. Then, you pass to the next id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
df2['Assigns'] = pd.Series(df1['Qty'].reindex(df1.index.repeat(df1['Count']))[::-1].to_numpy().reshape(-1,3).tolist())
df2
```

Output:

```
  id  Score    Assigns
0  A     10  [7, 6, 5]
1  B      9  [5, 5, 5]
2  C      8  [5, 5, 4]
3  D      7  [4, 4, 4]
4  E      6  [4, 3, 3]
5  F      5  [3, 3, 3]
6  G      4  [2, 1, 1]
```

Details:

- `df1.index.repeat(df1['Count'])` -- repeats the index for dataframe
  row the number of times in df1['count']
- `reindex` build a new series with those repeated values based on the
  index from the previous statement
- Use the reverse element `[::-1]` to go from last to first
- Then build a new pandas Series using the `pd.Series` constructor and
  assign it to a dataframe column.

Comment: thanks for the help! But, how could I add Assigns to the df2? like I show in the example, I need the id and score, not the qty and the count  :(

Comment: @M.Weithofer Oops.  Easy fix. Changed df1 to df2.  Just assigning that new series to the correct dataframe.

Comment: Is the last row of your expected dataframe incorrect?  You have one 2's and two 1's?

Comment: thanks you were right!  Can you explain to me what that code does?